# Ashkenazic vs Sephardic Kaddish

Tags: sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, kaddish, nusach-ashkenaz, nusach-sefard

1 - The Sephardic Kaddish has this extra line near the beginning:

> וְיַצְמַח פֻּרְקָנֵהּ וִיקָרֵב מְשִׁיחֵהּ -- 
>   May His salvation blossom and His Messiah be near.

The Ashkenazic Kaddish omits that line.  Why?  (I understand Chabad keeps it.)

2 - In the Ashkenazic Kaddish, we ask God for **two** things:

> יְהֵא שְׁלָמָה רַבָּא מִן שְׁמַיָּא, וְחַיִּים -- 
>   May peace abundant descend from heaven, and life.

In the Sephardic Kaddish, we ask God for **twelve** things:

> יְהֵא שְׁלָמָה רַבָּא מִן שְׁמַיָּא,[וְ]חַיִּים [טוֹבִים]וְשָֹבָע וִישׁוּעָה וְנֶחָמָה וְשֵׁיזָבָהוּרְפוּאָה וּגְאֻלָּה וּסְלִיחָה וְכַפָּרָה,וְרֵוַח וְהַצָּלָה -- 
>   May peace abundant descend from heaven, and life, plenty, healing, solace, liberation, rescue, deliverance, atonement, forgiveness, redemption and salvation.

(We figure: As long as we have God on the phone, might as well! :-)  )

Is there a specific reason behind this difference?

Comment: As far as I know, the Ashkinazim are not against saying these things, they just are against additions in davening (except where it has already been accepted...), and the Sefardim added these lines hundreds of years ago and the Ashkinazim just never did.

Comment: @Mordechai It really seems that it's an older variant, since Rambam has some of these words: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1508042/jewish/Order-of-Prayers-Text-of-the-Blessings-of-Shemoneh-Esreh.htm

Comment: See also this as well: https://archive.org/details/kaddishk00poolrich/page/37

Comment: Right, eight or nine hundred years ago.